# Why does Unicorn redirect to my root domain name? (on Gitlab)

Tags: redirect, nginx, debian, unicorn

I have a Unicorn server running at `localhost:8080` and it always redicts to my root domain when I do `curl -O http://localhost:8080`. I have *no idea* where this problem comes from and I appreciate any assistance in fixing this problem. Please let me know if you need any additional information.

If you're asking, "what have you tried", since last night I have tried to resolve this issue by doing changes to the NGinx configuration, `/etc/hosts`, the hostname. I can at least tell that it's not an issue with NGinx now (yeay).

**Unicorn**

```
$ curl -H 'Host: git.niklasrosenstein.com' http://localhost:8080 -i
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Mon, 18 Jan 2016 14:29:08 GMT
Status: 302 Found
Connection: close
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Location: http://niklasrosenstein.com
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Request-Id: 1a63e4a4-a5fe-4544-8f74-8b1bd0117a57
X-Runtime: 0.271394

<html><body>You are being <a href="http://niklasrosenstein.com">redirected</a>.</body></html>
```

Comment: If Nginx is not involved, consider removing the Nginx tag.

Answer (score 1):

Since only Unicorn is involved, the problem must be somewhere in your Unicorn configuration.

- Check your Unicorn configuration file
- Try writing a "Hello World" app to serve with Unicorn. Does it behave the same? If the "Hello World" doesn't exhibit this behavior, the issue is in app logic or configuration.
- Search in your app code for redirection logic or  mentions of the domain name it's being redirected to.
- Run: `sudo netstat -nlp | grep ':8080`. Confirm the process running on port 8080 is what you think it is.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately this is a GitLab instance and I have no idea about the code. :-) I have searched the GitLab configuration files of `gitlab.yml` and `unicorn.rb` thoroughly and there is only one mention of `git.niklasrosenstein.com` in `gitlab.yml`. I appreciate your reply, though I came across [Gogs](http://gogs.io) which worked after 30 minutes of setup, as opposed to GitLab with which I filled around for 8 hours +. Even though I'd like to know where the problem is, I don't have the commitment to continue investigating much deeper than the config files. :) Cheers